# Why are class methods listed twice?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I hit tab on variables which are of a certain type (like numpy arrays) I get all the methods listed twice. See below[image]

Any reason why this might be?  My PATH has anaconda listed twice

```
/Users/demetri/anaconda3/bin:/Users/demetri/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Might that have something to do with it?  If so, how can I remove one copy from my PATH?

Comment: `export PYTHONPATH="/Users/demetri/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin"`

Comment: @Aiven What does that do?  Can't I just edit the PATH directly?

Comment: if you want to edit it from code: `import sys; sys.path.pop('/Users/demetri/anaconda3/bin')`

Comment: another way is to find cause of problem: maybe in your .bash_profile or .bashrc (or .zshrc or whatever) export of conda doubled

Comment: @Aiven Yea, looks like there are two copis in my bash_profile.  Should I just delete one?

Comment: yes, and relaunch shell

Comment: @Aiven That removed the copy from my path, but the classe still appear twice.  Thanks though

Comment: have you restarted jupyter session? Maybe jupyter has some kind of "clear cache" function that remove and rebuild packages indexes

Comment: @Aiven restarted jupyter, and computer.  Maybe there is a way to clear cache.  Will check

Comment: I've found something in `~/Library/Jupyter/runtime` (`jupyter --data-dir` command) but it doesn't look like interpreter indexes tho... The last resort will be completely reinstall jupyter but does this problem worth it? (:

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an error in `ipykernel`.  Installing an older version fixed the issue.